# Unable to post to facebook page's feed via an application

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api

I'm unable to post to my website's facebook page wall via my facebook application even though it has the publish_stream, offline_access & manage_pages permission for posting to the page (along with its correct access token).

The application is able to post to **'/page_id/links/'** but not to **'/page_id/feed/'**.

See the code below:

```
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(settings.FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN_FOR_FB_APP)
    attachment = {}
    message = 'Hello! check the link!'
    site = Site.objects.get_current()   

    attachment['name'] = '%s' % idea.title
    attachment['link'] = 'http://%s%s' %(site,idea.get_absolute_url())
    attachment['caption'] = 'addressing problem "%s"' % idea.problem                
    attachment['description'] = '%s' % striptags(idea.desc)
    attachment['properties'] = {'See more': {'text':'Featured ideas', 'href':'http://%s' % site}} 
    # this works; posts to /fbpage/links/
    graph.put_object(settings.FACEBOOK_PAGE, "links", message=message, **attachment) 
    # this does not work; posts to /fbpage/feed/
    graph.put_wall_post(message, attachment, settings.FACEBOOK_PAGE)
```

Comment: no error! the action is successfull but I don't see anything on the wall but I see a notification counter at top which vanishes when I click it with nothing displayed.

Comment: Check the link you are posting via the Debug tool, and try to post it directly when you are on facebook.com – do you get any messages maybe, that the domain is blocked?

Comment: Ohh! Got the error! I was using may be a very generic another access token (not the fb page's) which did not throw any error while posting! May be it posted to somewhere else! But the links did show up correctly! Quite weird!

Answer (score 0):

I posted my solution to **get the right access token** in this question:
[How to get the access token to post on behalf of a facebook page via a custom application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317398/how-to-post-to-a-facebook-page-via-a-facebook-application)